# How to easily publish a multi-container asp.net core web app and wep api to a remote kubernetes kluster

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, kubernetes, asp.net-core-webapi

So I recently got into `docker` and `kubernetes` and I have a kubernetes cluster set up on a remote vm(linux, kubeadm) and I'm wondering if there is a solution **suitable for production** that I can easily use to deploy my multi-container asp.net core web application. I have been trying to solve this issue for the past week and found nothing that suits my needs. I have been trying to use `bridge to kubernetes` but I can only get that to work locally on my windows machine and not remotely onto my linux vm. [this is the layout of my appliction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stKRc.png)
Ask me if you need any additional information as I'm still new to this stuff.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use  Azure CLI to do this [check this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYIm_swpCoY).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `Jenkins` is just what I needed!